# Table is not centralized

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

```
<?php
  $query = "select * from patient ";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection , $query);

  while ($count = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

      # code...
  echo  "<table class='table table-hover'><thead><tr>".
                "<th>id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>phone</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
                <th>update</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>";?>
              <?php if (isset($count['name'])) { 
               echo  "<td>" . $count['id']. "</td>
                <td>" .ucwords($count['name']) ."</td>
                <td>". $count['phone'] . "</td>
                <td>" .$count['addeddate'] ."</td>
                <td>". ucwords($count['address']). "</td>
                <td>". "</td>
                <td>".  "</td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>";
      }
  }
 ?>
```

I am getting data from the database and displaying it in table but I wanted to display the table heading once this code is repeating the headings again and again. Any help?

Comment: Put you table heading above/before the while loop, and close the table after/below the close of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$query = "select * from patient ";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

$html = "<table class='table table-hover'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
         <th>id</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>phone</th>
         <th>Date</th>
         <th>Address</th>
         <th>Delete</th>
         <th>update</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>";


while ($count = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if (isset($count['name'])) {
        $html .= "<tr><td>" . $count['id'] . "</td>
                <td>" . ucwords($count['name']) . "</td>
                <td>" . $count['phone'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $count['addeddate'] . "</td>
                <td>" . ucwords($count['address']) . "</td>
                <td>" . "</td>
                <td>" . "</td>
              </tr>";
    }
}

echo $html .= "</tbody></table>";
?>
```

**Comment answer:** Last tow tds for delete and update link

```
        <td><a href='delete.php?id=" . $count['id'] . "'>Delete</a></td>
        <td><a href='update.php?id=" . $count['id'] . "'>update</a></td>
```

Comment: one more thing i want to ask if i want to insert delete in the second last <td> so i just click on link and than it will be deleted how can i do that ?

Comment: So you should accept the answer and give a up-vote :D

Answer (score 2):

Move

```
<table class='table table-hover'><thead><tr>".
                "<th>id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>phone</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
                <th>update</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
```

from the while loop to outside the loop

ie,

```
<?php
  $query = "select * from patient ";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection , $query);
<table class='table table-hover'><thead><tr>".
                "<th>id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>phone</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
                <th>update</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
  while ($count = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

      # code...
  echo  "
              <tr>";?>
              <?php if (isset($count['name'])) { 
               echo  "<td>" . $count['id']. "</td>
                <td>" .ucwords($count['name']) ."</td>
                <td>". $count['phone'] . "</td>
                <td>" .$count['addeddate'] ."</td>
                <td>". ucwords($count['address']). "</td>
                <td><a href='delete.php?id=".$count['id']."'>delete</a></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>

            ";
      }
  }
    ?>
</tbody>
          </table>
```

where delete.php has the code to delete entry and the corresponding id is sent as querystring to delete.php

Comment: Ditto with the footer bit

Comment: one more thing i want to ask if i want to insert delete in the second last <td> so i just click on link and than it will be deleted how can i do that ?

Comment: yes..as i said on clicking the link, the corresponding id is sent as query string to delete.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the table heading and footer out of the while loop.